# MongoDB Regular Expression:  Contains an e-mail inside a string

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

Given that I have a string such as

```
"Donald Trump <donald@trump.com>" 
"Art Job <art@job.com>"
```

How can I find every row that contains "donald@trump.com" using MongoDB in Rails?

Thanks

Comment: What MongoDB library are you using? Mongoid? MongoMapper?

Comment: Look at the regular expressions support of your driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.TUTORIAL.html):

```
search_string = params['search']

# Constructor syntax coll.find({"name" => Regexp.new(search_string)})

# Literal syntax coll.find({"name" => /#{search_string}/})
```

Beware though... You can't use an index with this query since your regex isn't anchored to the front of the string.

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't seem to work when the email is inside "< >".

Comment: Probably because it has no space between the email and the "< >"?

Comment: It it probably really dangerous to use your params, unfiltered, in a query directly. You'll want to run it through some kind of sanitizer first, at least. I don't know if the mongo ruby driver does that by default or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform such a search only using regular expressions:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions

In your case you won't be able to search in a efficient way except you denormalize your data and store your email addresses in a dedicated attribute of the document.

No idea about Ruby but every driver should have support for regular expressions.

Comment: Wouldn't that be normalizing the data rather than denormalizing?