# Changing Search Query from Mysql to MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

This is the query for Mysql database

```
@names = Name.order_by(:name) .where("name like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
```

I want to change it to Mongodb Database query since i am using Mongoid.
I did this

```
  @names = Name.order_by(:name).where(name: /#{Regexp.escape(:term)}/i)
```

I get this error

```
<h1>
  NoMethodError
    in NamesController#index
</h1>
<pre>undefined method `__sort_option__&#x27; for :name:Symbol</pre>
```

Comment: I think you should be using `find`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914771/mongodb-regular-expression-contains-an-e-mail-inside-a-string

Comment: find only show 1 data i think so we have to use where here . Because I have to search all related data started from given input alphabet.

Comment: `find` returns the entire document. The linked example uses `find` and a regular expression.